# Creating a table with too many inputs

Tags: php, sql

I was wondering if you can give me an advice in creating a table for tooth information?

I have here an image : http://i51.tinypic.com/2yzcvh2.png

The dentist choose the number of the said tooth that needs medication/repair/etc. I'm thinking of it as a checkbox in the layout.

I'm confused on what to do in the tables. So far I have these fields in my mind

tooth_table

-
..patient_id [fk]

..name[fk]

..last_visit[fk]

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach (*syntax*: `table_name: column1, column2, ...`):

```
patients: id, name, ...

visits: id, partient_id, last_visit, ...

teeth_actions: id, patient_id, tooth_id, count, type, note, ...

teeth: id, name, ...
```

I'm not a medic so I'm not sure if all the teeth have some latin names or something... But it's good to have the teeth numbered and marked, not only on a picture.

Please specify further your question if something's not clear in this ;)

Comment: thank you for you fast reply. ok im sorry i didnt specify me question. what confuses me is that if i submit the form will all the checked values come to 1 field on the table ? because if i need to get the values on the field for editing page i would just select the field and show the checked values then update it. that is what i meant. will i put 1 single field to hold all the checked values or give 1 field for each tooth ?

Comment: @renz, please distinguish between fields and rows. 'Field' is usually used for the "properties" of an object in OOP. That aside - how the data is stored depends entirely on your application. You might want to force the user to **first** create a patient entry (takes one row in the first table) and then allow him to input other things. As for the teeth actions - every teeth/action takes one row in the third table. So in your case you just check which teeth were checked in the form and save _only_ the ones where a medical procedure is required (others -without entry- are implicitly without proc)

Comment: thanks , im so sorry again for misleading. im in a project and its on a rush. its almost the end of the semester. ill try to follow your answers here. gives me the idea now. thanks again.

Comment: @renz, don't be sorry, that's what SO is for ;)  Interesting, here in central Europe the semester is just starting.